# BJT in Saturation

Tags: transistors, bjt, saturation

Is it possible for the base current to exceed the collector current for a BJT in saturation mode? (If the base current was increased without the collector current increasing at all)

Comment: Certainly possible. At some point, the Vce(sat) will stop decreasing and will begin to increase as the base current increases (for a given collector current), so it's not something that is necessarily useful.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How does it happen?

Comment: The base-collector junction is forward biased in saturation- so current does not just flow to the emitter, but also to the collector.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. Consider the figure below.

[image]

The collector current at saturation will be
$$I_{Csat} = \frac{V_{CC}-V_{CEsat}}{R_C} \approx \frac{V_{CC}}{R_C}$$

The base current is given by,
$$I_B = \frac{V_{CC} - V_{BE}}{R_B} \approx \frac{V_{CC}}{R_B}$$

So it is clear that the currents at saturation are entirely decided by the resistors and hence base current can be greater than the collector current at saturation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is obvious that the base current can exceed the collector current if you consider the limiting case where the collector is open-circuit.  The collector current will be 0, but you can still drive from 0 to the maximum allowed base current thru the base.  With the collector open, base to emitter just looks like a diode.

Comment: Didn`t the questioner ask for saturation mode conditions?